# Angular Server-side Rendering: Router-outlet doesn't render HTML from lazy loading pages

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, router-outlet

In SPA (Angular) I'm placing all page components inside PagesComponent `app/pages`. For example: homepage is in `app/pages/home`, news are in `app/pages/news`. Routes are working with lazy load. Until this point everything works fine.

However,  when I try to apply Server-side Rendering (Angular Universal) `router-outlet` from `pages.component.html` doesn't render anything. The only way to make SSR work is to move HomeComponent page from `child-routes.module.ts` to `pages.routing.ts`. The following code is the original code without moving the component.

In short words, SSR doesn't render HTML for components loaded with lazy loading (inside `child-routes.module.ts`).

Is there a way to make SSR work with lazy loading?

**app/app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { PagesRoutingModule } from './pages/pages.routing';  
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      initialNavigation: 'enabled'
    }),
    PagesRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app/pages/pages.routing.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', 
      component: PagesComponent,
      loadChildren: () => import('./child-routes.module').then( m => m.ChildRoutesModule )
    }
]  

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class PagesRoutingModule { }
```

**app/pages/child-routes.module.ts**

```
const childRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'news', component: NewsComponent}]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(childRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class ChildRoutesModule { }
```

**app/app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app/pages/pages.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<main><router-outlet></router-outlet></main>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core? If so, in Visual Studio check the Output window. If SSR fails for whatever reason, you'll see the cause there.

Comment: Hi Ricardo - have you found any solution for this